# UI-Grid custom filter restore listTerm

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

When using UI-grid custom filters, the filters are stored in a listTerm object and in the default term object (Separated by commas).

The default grid restore tries to restore the term object which breaks the filter.
 If I log the state in the console I can see a filters array for each column containing 2 objects a "listTerm" array containing the selected terms and a term object containing the same values separated by commas as
 term :"filvalue1, filvalue2,"
I am sure the grid is restoring this comma separated object and treating it as a single filter text.
any ideas how to get it recognize the comma as a separator or to do this in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is trying to achieve the same thing (persistent multi-select filter ) I managed to do it by adding a seperators handler as filters to the columns where I am using costum filtering :

```
filter: {
      condition:  function(searchTerm, cellValue) {
        var separators = ['-', '/', ':', ';', ','];
          var strippedValue = searchTerm.split(new RegExp(separators.join('|'), 'g'));
          var bReturnValue = false;
          for(iIndex in strippedValue){
                var sValueToTest = strippedValue[iIndex];
                sValueToTest = sValueToTest.replace(" ", "");
            if (cellValue.toLowerCase().indexOf(sValueToTest.toLowerCase()) >= 0)
                bReturnValue = true;
          }


        return bReturnValue;

      }
    }
```

Credit goes to Bruno Costa
[How to filter with multiple values in ui-grid? (angularjs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085872/how-to-filter-with-multiple-values-in-ui-grid-angularjs/42159476#42159476)